# Mobx reaction on sub array change/remove

Tags: arrays, reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

How to react to change in array of array?

```js
var todos = mobx.observable([
    {
        title: "Make Pasta", 
        subtasks: [  
            { title: 'Pasta' }, { title: 'Salt' },
        ] 
    },
    { 
        title: "Make coffee", 
        subtasks: [ 
            { title: 'Hot Water' }, { title: 'Milk' },
        ] 
    }
]);

const reactionSubtask = mobx.reaction(
    () => todos.map(todo => todo.subtasks),
    subtasks => console.log("reaction subtasks >", subtasks)
);

const reactionTask = mobx.reaction(
    () => todos.map(todo => todo.title),
    titles => console.log("reaction title >", titles.join(', '))
);

const resultSubtaskRemove = todos[1].subtasks.remove(todos[1].subtasks[0]);
console.log('Subtask remove result >', resultSubtaskRemove);

const resultSubTaskAdd = todos[1].subtasks.push({title: 'Filter'});
console.log('Subtask add result >', resultSubTaskAdd);

const resultSubTaskChange = todos[1].subtasks[0].title = 'Change titled';
console.log('Subtask change result >', resultSubTaskChange);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/mobx/lib/mobx.umd.js"></script>
```

Reaction is not executed.

In my case I use mobx-react and my React components are not update when I change children array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First reaction doesn't work as expected because you access observable property which is a reference to an observable array. You code modifies the array, but not the reference itself.

This line

```
todos[0].subtasks = 'changed'
```

will invoke first reaction.

If you want to react to subtask addition/removal you need to change your reaction to something like this

```
const reactionSubtask = mobx.reaction(
    () => todos.map(todo => todo.subtasks.slice()),
    subtasks => console.log("reaction subtasks >", subtasks)
);
```

Second reaction doesn't work because you change title of a subtask, but reaction accesses title of tasks.

I would highly recommend you to read MobX docs since they go into great details when describing what MobX reacts to. Moreover, there is [an example](https://mobx.js.org/best/react.html#incorrect-use-an-observable-but-without-accessing-any-of-its-properties) which explains why the first reaction doesn't work.